# rsync to remote ssh or to local iscsi

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync, iscsi

I'm curious of anyone knows a link to or can elaborate upon this design question:
I have a server that I would like to make a backup copy of data from.  I have a second server that is iscsi-enabled.  My question involved using rsync to one of two things.
My concern is is better to log on to second server via ssh and execute rsync.
Server 1
rsync /data/ server2@remote.location /backup_data/

Or is is better (subjectively and/or objectively) to mount a local iscsi share from server 2 one to server 1 and execute a 'local' file transfer.

Server 1
mkdir /backup_data/
mount iscsi.share@remote.location /backup_data/
rsync /data/ /backup_data/

One would think that this question/answer has come up before but I can't seem to find an answer. Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question.

I'm really looking for a pros/cons list to go with.
Thanks ahead of time folks!

Comment: other than resiliency as a plus there's not a much of difference........ essentially you'll get same output.

Comment: Resiliency?  Can you please clarify?  I suspect you are referring to iSCSI being able to reconnect after a reboot or whatever

Comment: precisely, and in case you loose connection from one node second is still able to reach target.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

iISCSI it is, thanks Michal!  I appreciate the follow up